# Identify the parameterized type and get field values from the particular object

Tags: generics, java-8

I am trying to create a clause generator that will help me generate a partial part of the where clause given a List of objects

I have the below method, in the appendToClause method I would like to identify the parameterized type T, and use reflections to get the declared fields and their values.

1. Do I need to pass the class type of the object, would that make it easier or can I use reflections to identify the the class type of T ? How do I find the class type of T.
2. How do I get the declared fields and their values from the parametrised objects of type T using reflections?

   ```
   public void generateClause(List<T> objects) {
       int id = 0;
       StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();
       Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
       for (T key : objects) {
           if (clause.length() > 0) {
               clause.append(" or ");
           }
           appendToClause(key, clause, params, id);
           id++;
       }
   }

   private void appendToClause(T key, StringBuilder clause, Map<String, Object> params, int Id) {
   ```

   }

Comment: There is no declaration of `<T>` in your code.

Comment: T could be any object type. Please can you elaborate if this is not what you expect?

Comment: Apparently, `T` is a type parameter at your class, but there is no reason why *we*  should guess about it. In the context of your code snippet, `<T>` is meaningless. E.g. a `List<Object>` may still contain objects of type `String`, so why should it matter whether these strings are stored in a `List<Object>` or `List<String>` (or `List<Comparable<?>>` or `List<Serializable>`)…

Answer (score 0):

Your function will generate an error like that, because T does not exist as it is, what you need is :

```
public <T> void generateClause(List<T> objects) {}
```

About your questions, you are looking for [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).